# Windows sockets: What can cause send() to stockpile silently?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi

I have a C++ program which uses Windows sockets to communicate in the LAN with another instance of the same program. This works in general. For a few customers it doesn't.

Socket creation, listen and accept succeed. The computer who created the socket can send() a message and the second computer will recv() it. However, when it sends a reply (using send(), successfully), this doesn't arrive at the first computer.

If I artificially increase the message size, send() reports to send the first 65564(!) bytes successfully, but when I call it again for the rest, it returns -1 and WSAGetLastError return 183 (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS). Again, nothing arrives at the first computer. Firewalls / AV programs are already turned off.

It seems to me as if send() is keeping the data in some kind of "outbox" without really sending it. What could cause such a thing?

Comment: Are you using TCP or UDP?

Comment: Is your first computer calling `recv()`? On which socket?

Comment: TCP. Socket is created with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)

Comment: I'm polling recv() in a background thread and I use port 1201.

Comment: Also, make sure that the error code is not from a previous call. 183 sounds more like an error you'd get when you initialize winsocks twice..

Comment: "and I use port 1201" - `recv` is not called on a port. Make sure you call `recv` on the right _socket_

Comment: Did you notice anything special with the problematic machines ? Does pings work in both ways on these ? Any other TCP LAN software you could use to test ? This would determine if the problem is software or network related.

Comment: @Arkadiy: Oops, you're right!! Depending on the user settings I do call WSAStartup twice. With different versions. Is this worth running another test with the customer or won't it matter? / Socket: I'm pretty sure I use the right socket. The program works normally just nice.

Comment: @ElderBug: Sorry, nothing that I noticed. Ping and Windows shared folders seem to work normally.

Comment: About `WSAStartup`, the MSDN says _An application can call WSAStartup more than once..._ and _An application must call the WSACleanup function for every successful time the WSAStartup function is called._

Comment: So what is the real error code?

Comment: If 183 really comes from the double initialization (although ERROR_ALREADY_INITIALIZED would be more appropriate), then this means that send() doesn't set the WSA last error state, despite returning -1, doesn't it?

Comment: Post some code. WINSOCK errors are 10000+. 183 isn't one of them. You need to call `WSAGetLastError()` immediately after getting the error, not after doing something else first.

Comment: I do check the error immediately. Not all WSA codes are >=10000, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You still need to post some code. 183 isn't on the list you cited.

Comment: I agree with EJP. 183 is not an error code that `send()` reports.  `WSAGetLastError()` simply delegates to `GetLastError()` internally, WinSock does not have its own error code storage.  So the 183 is coming from something else.